# Issue with String position appending C program

Tags: c

I am trying to write program for piglatin. I was not getting the output what I am expecting.

take the first letter of a “word” and appending that letter to the end of the word with “ay” added to the end as well.

Input : Darrin, what are you doing with 500 and 100?
Output:  arrin, hatway reaay ouyay oingday ithway 500 ndaay 100?
Expected Output: arrinday,hatway reay ouyay oingday ithway 500 nday 100?

What's wrong with output : First word not appended with ay

Since I am appending 'ay', I need eliminate the extra 'a' if the word starts with a or end's with 'a'.  I just need add ay at the end instead of first letter + ay.   For example: Input is Alex and allen are 500 Output should be lexay nday llenay

Also if the starting letter is not alphabet then we should return the same word.

Please help me to solve this

```
#include <stdio.h>                 
#include <stdlib.h>                
#include <stdint.h>                
#include <string.h>                

static char inputBuffer[100];
static char outputBuffer[100];


void translate (void)
{
  char bufferValue;
  char firstLetter;
  int j = 0, k = 0, m = 0;

  printf("\n");

  while (j < (sizeof(inputBuffer) - 1))
  {
    bufferValue = inputBuffer[j];

    if (((bufferValue >= 'A') && (bufferValue <= 'Z')) || ((bufferValue >= 'a') && (bufferValue <= 'z')))
    {
      if (j == 0) 
      {
        firstLetter = bufferValue; 

      }
      else if (inputBuffer[j-1] == ' ') 
      {
        firstLetter = bufferValue;                                      
      }
      else
      {
        printf("%c", bufferValue);
        outputBuffer[m] = bufferValue; m++;
      }
    }    
    else if ((bufferValue == ' ') && !(
    ((inputBuffer[j-1] < 'A') || 
    ((inputBuffer[j-1] > 'Z') && (inputBuffer[j-1] < 'a')) || 
    (inputBuffer[j-1] > 'z'))))
    {
      printf("%cay%c", firstLetter, bufferValue);
      outputBuffer[m] = firstLetter; m++;
      outputBuffer[m] = 'a'; m++;
      outputBuffer[m] = 'y'; m++;
      outputBuffer[m] = bufferValue; m++;
      firstLetter = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%c", bufferValue);
      outputBuffer[m] = bufferValue; m++;
    }
    j++;

  } 

  printf("\n final output: %s",outputBuffer);

   return;
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("enter the string\t");
  fflush(stdin);
  gets(inputBuffer);

  printf ("\nInput buffer contents:  %s", inputBuffer);
  translate();
  return 0;             
}
```

Comment: First observation: `sizeof` does not give you `strlen`.

Comment: You should consider using `isalpha()` and related macros from `<ctype.h>`.  You should avoid using global variables instead of function parameters.  You should ensure that you don't overflow your output buffer.  I'm not sure what you should produce for an input string `" Did O'Rourke and Giffen-Hailey go out at two o'clock?"` (with a leading blank, and with punctuation like `'` and `-` in the words, and `?` at the end).  I think I would expect to isolate 'words' and then deal with the pig-latin transformation of each word.

Comment: have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that you didn't see the forest through the trees which made the implementation awful to read. To add insult to injury, you decided to break the basic rules of code locality (not using globals unless necessary) and DRY (functions to tell if a charater is a letter exist in the standard library of any language I can think of, don't reimplement it), which made it pretty much irrecoverable as far as maintenance is concerned.

Now, let's read the task description again:

> take the first letter of a “word” and appending that letter to the end of the word with “ay” added to the end as well.

Notice what already stands out because of quoting: **word**.

So, I'd divide the implementation into two distinct tasks:

1. Iterate through a sentence word by word.
2. Once you can reliably identify words, do the piglatin thing.

The end result of might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void piglatinize(const char* in)
{
    static const char* SEP = " .,?";  // word separators

    // Iterate input by words
    const char *sep = NULL, *word = NULL, *end = in;
    while (sep = end,  // separators from previous word end
           word = &end[strspn(end, SEP)],  // start of word
           end = &word[strcspn(word, SEP)],  // end of word
           *sep)  // iterate until we hit terminating zero character
    {
        int wordlen = (int)(end - word);
        int seplen = (int)(word - sep);
        if (wordlen > 0 && isalpha(word[0]))  // word starts with a letter, pig it!
        {
            char firstletter = tolower(word[0]);
            const char* suffix = (firstletter == 'a') ? "y" : "ay";
            printf("%.*s%.*s%c%s",
                seplen, sep,            // separators from previous word
                wordlen - 1, &word[1],  // word without first letter
                firstletter, suffix);
        }
        else  // not a real word, just print unchanged
        {
            printf("%.*s%.*s", seplen, sep, wordlen, word);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    piglatinize("Darrin, what are you doing with 500 and 100?");
}
```

I admit the `while` loop continuation condition is a handful. If you have trouble understanding this example you might want to read on [strspn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn) (and its opposite `strcspn`) and [the comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: Thanks for optimizing and helping me to understand. Could you please also help me to eliminate the extra ''a'". Like "are" should be "reay"

Comment: @Bhavya The task description says nothing about that. Please update the task in your question giving the circumstances under which the extra "a" (or is it all vowels?) should be dropped. It's hard to help solve a problem with an unclear goal.

Comment: Corrected the solution to skip the extra 'a' if the word starts (the pigged word ends) with an 'a'.

Comment: I want to dynamically create the array and pass to your function  during my testing in Main function. Could you please also help me in creating that Inputbuffer and output buffer dynamically

Comment: @Bhavya I've answered your question, you can easily adapt my solution it to fit your needs concerning in- and output with some research. Note that this site is about answering one particular question at a time, not relieving people from all their (home?)work.

Comment: Sure, I will do that atleast could you please help me to store the final result in array.  I will do my rest of home work. From you Program, it shows me we are directly printing  but my original request is to store them in array and then print

Answer (score 1):

> First word not appended with ay

The problem is just not that only the first word is not being appended by first letter and `ay`, but whenever you have some *non alphabet* character at the end of a word (digits/special characters, except space), `ay` will not be appended to that word.

For example, try this input:

```
Darrin, what, are you doing with 500 and 100?
```

You'll get the output:

```
arrin, hat, reaay ouyay oingday ithway 500 ndaay 100?
```

So mainly, the problem is in the last `else` you have:

```
else
{
  printf("%c", bufferValue);
  outputBuffer[m] = bufferValue; m++;
}
```

See, when `,` comes immediately after a word, the control comes to this `else` and it just adds the `,` as it is, it does not append the `firstLetter` and `ay`.

But you can't always append `firstLetter` and `ay` in this `else`, you'll have to come up with some kind of condition, so you could separate the `500` and `Darrin,`, cause `500` will also go through this `else` statement.

Maybe, you could try checking if `firstLetter` is an alphabet or not, if it is, then append the `firstLetter` and `ay`, otherwise not.

```
else
{
    if ((firstLetter >= 'a' && firstLetter <= 'z') || (firstLetter >= 'A' && firstLetter <= 'Z'))
        printf("%cay", firstLetter);
        outputBuffer[m] = firstLetter; m++;
        outputBuffer[m] = 'a'; m++;
        outputBuffer[m] = 'y'; m++;
        firstLetter = ' ';
    }
    printf("%c", bufferValue);
    outputBuffer[m] = bufferValue; m++;
}
```

But this will still not process the words like `0abcdef,`, which do have alphabets in it, but start with some non-alphabet character, so that's your call, if you want to put them to the numbers category (like `500`), to leave them as they are, or to process them.

[Here](http://ideone.com/ngk4PP) is the working example.

P.S. I've made some other changes too (which don't affect your output), but the major change was what I explained (which does).

**EDIT**:

From the comments below:

> If the word starts with Vowel(a,e,i,o,u) then just add y else first letter + ay

You can write a function in your program called `isVowel` to check if some character is vowel or not:

```
int isVowel(char c)
{
    c = tolower(c);
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, you're adding `ay` at two places in your program:

In the `else if` and the last `else`:

```
outputBuffer[m] = firstLetter; m++;
outputBuffer[m] = 'a'; m++;
outputBuffer[m] = 'y'; m++;
firstLetter = ' ';
```

So, you can add an `if` at the statements `outputBuffer[m] = 'a'; m++;` to only add this `a` if the `firstLetter` is not a vowel:

```
outputBuffer[m] = firstLetter; m++;
if (!isVowel(firstLetter))
{
    outputBuffer[m] = 'a';
    m++;
}
outputBuffer[m] = 'y'; m++;
firstLetter = ' ';
```

change this at both places i.e. in the `else if` and `else`, and you'll be done.

I've updated the code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/ngk4PP)

Comment: It's working, Thanks for the help. Can you also help me to eliminate the Vowels.

Comment: you want to eliminate them all? From the output?

Comment: yes like this Say if input is are then output should be reay instead of reaay

Comment: `e` is also a vowel, are you sure, you don't want to remove that too?

Comment: Or you just want that if the first letter of the word is `a`, then just append `y` at the end of the word instead of `ay`?

Comment: yes, let's say If the word starts with Vowel(a,e,i,o,u) then just add y else first letter +ay

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Now I am trying to eliminate assign the static memory . I want to get the input and allocate the memory using memalloc and pass that pointer as input to Translate () function.       How to predict the Output buffer length

Comment: @Bhavya, as far as "How to predict the Output buffer length", based on my experience, Pig Latin expands the English original by a factor of 1.5 -- so doubling the input size would be a reasonable approach.